# Using host machines CA cert within Docker container

Tags: ssl, docker

For https access I need to add a CA cert file to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` on my Ubuntu host machine.

Currently my Dockerfile `RUN wget https...` is failing since the certificate verification is failing.

How can Docker use the host machine CA cert? Or is there an existing enhancement opened to allow this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few open bugs in this area:

https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1799

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4372

https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1435

https://github.com/deis/deis/issues/2230

Answer (score 0):

I've used CA and SSL certs via a passthrough mount, but this looks like you're trying to do it in the Dockerfile.

So my suggestion would be - copy the CA cert to the image as part of the Dockerfile, and then proceed as normal. Or drop to `http`, or run `wget --no-check-certificate` if you're happy with that.